# Copy text from webpage

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I want to copy a text from a dialogue box in a webpage by using VBS. I have tried this

```
dim copiedTxt 
'set copiedTxt = Browser("Finacle Universal Banking").Page("Finacle Universal Banking").Frame("HTMLDataFrm").WebEdit("_basic_docmsg_paraMsg").GetROProperty("value")
```

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail (what happens?)

Comment: set is for Objects. Use it without Set

Comment: Geert Bellekens problem is this statement is cant catch text from dialogue box.

Answer (score -1):

Use below statement only.

```
copiedTxt = Browser("Finacle Universal Banking").Page("Finacle Universal Banking").Frame("HTMLDataFrm").GetROProperty("value")
```

Please try by removing webedit. Try from the frame.

Comment: if i remove webedit this statement cant find dialgogue box i guess